Jenkins pipeline groovy script - parameter doesn't exist
I have this in the parameters section of my Jenkins declarative pipeline:

activeChoice(
        name: 'Repos',
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
        filterable: true,
        fallbackScript('return ["ERROR"]')
        script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [
                        script: """
return "${PARAM_REP_LIST}".replaceAll('"', '').split(",").findAll { it.toLowerCase().startsWith("rms") || it.toLowerCase().startsWith("pricing") } as List
                        """
                ]
        ]
),

The parameter PARAM_REP_LIST is defined because it expands in the activeChoice.  This works, but because of the parameter expansion of return "${PARAM_REP_LIST}" the script must be approved every time the variable changes.
When I try to access the variable directly by changing return "${PARAM_REP_LIST}".replaceAll('"', '').split(",").findAll { to return PARAM_REP_LIST.replaceAll('"', '').split(",").findAll { so that I am accessing the variable directly instead of expanding it, Jenkins reports an error that PARAM_REP_LIST does not exist.  I'm guessing the expansion is happening separately in the pipeline, but I really don't know.  Can someone enlighten me as to why?  And how to fix it?  I don't want PARAM_REP_LIST to be expanded because every time it changes the script has to be approved by an admin.
Edit:  The answer is to let the parameter expand and activate sandbox.  Complete working example:
activeChoice(
        name: 'PLATFORM',
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
        filterable: true,
        script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [
                        sandbox: true,
                        script: """
return [ '1',"2" ]
                        """
                ]
        ]
),
reactiveChoice(
        name: 'REPOS',
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
        filterable: true,
        script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [
                        sandbox: true,
                        script: """
if (PLATFORM.equals('1')) {
return "${PARAM_REP_LIST}".replaceAll('"', '').split(",").findAll { it.toLowerCase().startsWith("1") } as List
} else if (PLATFORM.equals('2')) {
return "${PARAM_REP_LIST}".replaceAll('"', '').split(",").findAll { it.toLowerCase().startsWith("2") } as List
} else {
return ['Please select a Platform first']
}

                        """
                ]
        ],
        referencedParameters: 'PLATFORM',
),

